# Doubt on convergence of a sequence of real numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a doubt on a very specific example of convergence of a sequence of real numbers. The example is as follows:

Prove that the sequences $\{a^n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to zero, where $0<a<1$.

By using the definition, I get that

\begin{gather}
a^n<\epsilon \\
\iff n<\frac{\ln\epsilon}{\ln a}
\end{gather}

but if I understand correctly, I should get an $n>$ some natural number. Can someone explain to me what the answer would be for this example?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget that logarithm with a base which is smaller than $1$ is a decreasing function. So it should be $n>\frac{ln(\epsilon)}{ln(a)}$.

Comment: Any natural number $\ge {\ln \epsilon \over \ln a}$ will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\ln$ is an strictly increasing function, you are right to say that
$$ a^n < \epsilon \implies n \ln a < \ln \epsilon$$
But notice that both $\ln a$ and $\ln \epsilon$ are negative numbers because $a$ and $\epsilon $ are less than $1$, so diving flips the inequality:
$$ n >\frac{\ln\epsilon}{\ln a} $$

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I saw in
"What is Mathematics?"
by Courant and Robbins.

Since $0 < a < 1$,
$a = \dfrac1{1+b}$
where
$b 
= \dfrac1{a}-1$,
so
$b > 0$.

By Bernoulli's inequality,
$(1+b)^n
\ge 1+nb
\gt nb
=n(\dfrac1{a}-1)
$
so
$a^n
=\dfrac1{(1+b)^n}
\lt \dfrac1{nb}
=\dfrac1{n(1/a-1)}
\to 0
$.